# Can we create a data type of class itself?

Tags: linked-list

I am learning data structures and recently I came across a book implementing linked list from scratch it had something like .

```
class ListNode{
    private ListNode next;
}
```

What exactly the code means and what it does .

Comment: Add the language tag.

Answer (score 0):

What that means is that objects of `class ListNode` will have a `private` member (not accessible outside the class) called `next` that will tell it the next `ListNode`on the linked list.

This is clearly a managed language (probably java or C#) and class objects are references to the memory that holds the actual object. If you where learning a non-managed language you may not have gotten as confused about this as the private member next would have been of pointer type.

Since the member object `next` will only be a reference to a memory having the layout described in the class definition there is no self-recursion for the type definition like you may think.

When the `ListNode` gets created `next` should be `null`. When it gets put into the list the `next` from the element before it will be set to this `ListNode` and the `next` from this `ListNode` will be set to the next element of the list (if there is any). 
So `next` effectively points to the memory where another `ListNode` has already been created with what ever data it is meant to have. The actual data for a `ListNode` has to be placed in other member variables. A generic one would simply have a `Object data;` member that would keep a generic object.

Hope this helps!

Comment: So you mean to say that the private variable next is datatype of the class and it holds the information about the other data's in the class and is used to access them. Or it contains the information about where the next ListNode is present in the memory. Which one is actually write So if we choose other languages like C or C++ we could use pointer to findout the next memory right?.

Comment: When the ListNode gets created next should be null. When it gets put into the list the next from the element before it will be set to this ListNode and the next from this list node will be set to the next element of the list (if there is any)

Comment: So next effectively points to the memory where another ListNode has already been created with what ever data it is meant to have. The actual data for a ListNode has to be placed in other member variables. A generic one would simply have a Object data; member that would keep a generic object.